# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 8, size is 0

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, indexoutofboundsexception

When I drag list up and try to show all list Item that time it gives me error like this.
and this is my AsyncTask which working in background.
please give some error free Hints....
This asyncTask is called by services in a few seconds.

```
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(
            String... args) {
        String url = args[0];
        rssItems = rssParser.getRSSFeedItems(url);
        FeedDBHandler rssDb = new FeedDBHandler(getApplicationContext());
        // RSSItem rssItem;
        rssItems.size();
        Log.i("size", "size:" + rssItems.size());

        for (RSSItem item : rssItems) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // Truncating description
            String description = item.getDescription();
            if (description.length() > 100)
                description = description.substring(3, 97) + "..";

            // Store in database
            rssItem = new RSSItem(item.getTitle(), item.getLink(),
                    item.getCategory(), description, item.getPubdate());

            // check if not exist -notify and insert
            if (!rssDb.isExistItem(item.getLink())) {
                createNotification(item.getTitle());
                rssDb.addFeed(rssItem);
            }
            createNotification(item.getTitle());
            if (map != null) {
                map.put(TAG_TITLE, item.getTitle());
                map.put(TAG_LINK, item.getLink());
                map.put(TAG_CATEGORY, item.getCategory());
                map.put(TAG_DESRIPTION, description);
                map.put(TAG_PUB_DATE, item.getPubdate());

                rssItemList.add(map);
            }
        }

        return rssItemList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> rssItemList) {
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(AndroidRSSReaderList.this,
                rssItemList, R.layout.rss_item_list_row,
                new String[] { TAG_LINK, TAG_TITLE, TAG_DESRIPTION,
                        TAG_PUB_DATE }, new int[] { R.id.page_url,
                        R.id.title, R.id.link, R.id.pub_date });

        // updating listview
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.deferNotifyDataSetChanged();
        // lv.onDataSetChanged();

        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        // pDialog.dismiss();

    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: you got any idea why the list still contains 0 elements after your http-call?

Comment: i did not used http call and please give me some hint by code so i can understand very clear..
Thanks

Comment: first of all it is very useful to supply the spot where the error occurs. Narrows down a problem a decent chunk.

Comment: actually when i move generated list up that time it is unfortunately stops

Comment: error should be in the ` rssItemList.add(map);` line..
it goes empty while moving up according to my opinion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        rssItemList.clear();
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(
            String... args) {
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        FeedDBHandler rssDb = new FeedDBHandler(getApplicationContext());

        // listing all RSSItems from SQLite
        List<RSSItem> rssList = rssDb.getAllItems();

        // loop through each RSSItem
        for (int i = 0; i < rssList.size(); i++) {

            RSSItem s = rssList.get(i);

            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(TAG_TITLE, s.getTitle());
            map.put(TAG_LINK, s.getLink());
            map.put(TAG_CATEGORY, s.getCategory());
            map.put(TAG_DESRIPTION, s.getDescription());
            map.put(TAG_PUB_DATE, s.getPubdate());
            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            rssItemList.add(map);

        }
        return rssItemList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> rssItemList) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        AndroidRSSReaderList.this, rssItemList,
                        R.layout.rss_item_list_row, new String[] {
                                TAG_LINK, TAG_TITLE, TAG_PUB_DATE,
                                TAG_DESRIPTION }, new int[] {
                                R.id.page_url, R.id.title, R.id.pub_date,
                                R.id.link });

                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
    }
```

I have solved this questions by some changes...